# Need something like greater-than-or-equal

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to have something like:

```
int x = arrayX.count;
int y = arrayY.count;

if (x >= y) {
//do something
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `int x = 5; int y = 5; if(x >=y) { //something }` should work

Comment: Without specifying the type of x and y this question cannot be answered

Comment: So "where is the question"? (Usually, if one down-votes, one should also vote to close, even if the converse does not hold.)

Comment: Did you even bother to try it?

Comment: sorry, it was a stupid mistake. The problem was somewhere else. so I asked the wrong question. please stop voting me down.. I'm a beginner.. and thanks for the kind answers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work as long as `x` and `y` are primitive values such as `int` or `float`. (It won't work on objects like `NSNumber`. You would need to obtain primitive values from that object using one of the provided methods).

Comment: Of course, which is why I said it would work on primitive values. `intValue` and `floatValue` return primitives.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the -compare: message with many types of objects:

```
if ([[NSDate date] compare:self.targetDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    ...  // targetDate is in the future.
}
else if ([[NSDate date] compare:self.targetDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    ...  // targetDate is in the past.
}
else {  // NSOrderedSame
    ...  // Dates are exactly the same.
}
```

Sample code. Not good code.  :-)